# Python Tulpe Key For Dict Partial Lookup

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary with a tuple of 5 values as a key. For example:

D[i,j,k,g,h] = value.

Now i need to process all elements with a certain partial key pair (i1,g1):

I need now for each pair (i1,g1) all values that have i == i1 and g == g1 in the full key.

What is an pythonic and efficient way to retrieve this, knowing that i need the elements for all pairs and each full key belongs to exactly one partial key?

Is there a more appropriate data structure than dictionaries?

One reference implementation is this:

```
    results = {}
    for i in I:
        for g in G:
            results[i,g] = []

    for i,j,k,g,h in D:
        if i1 == i and g1 == g:
            results[i,g].append(D[i,j,k,g,h])
```

Comment: do you have a precompiled list of all possible values of `i,k,g,h`?  In which case `itertools.product` would likely provide the wanted functionality.

Comment: Yes i have that. Its the set I,G,K,H,J.

Comment: So for I and G i know that all combination are used, but for a given i1 and g1 not all combination of K, H, J are used.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know all the valid values for the different indices you can get **all possible** keys using `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools
I = [3,6,9]
J = range(10)
K = "abcde"
G = ["first","second"]
H = range(10,20)

for tup in itertools.product(I,J,K,G,H):
    my_dict[tup] = 0
```

To restrict the indices generated just put a limit on one / several of the indices that gets generated, for instance all of the keys where `i = 6` would be:

```
itertools.product((6,), J,K,G,H)
```

A function to let you specify you want all the indices where `i==6 and g =="first"` would look like this:

```
def partial_indices(i_vals=I, j_vals=J, k_vals=K, g_vals = G, h_vals = H):
    return itertools.product(i_vals, j_vals, k_vals, g_vals, h_vals)

partial_indices(i_vals=(6,), g_vals=("first",))
```

Or assuming that not all of these are present in the dictionary you can also pass the dictionary as an argument and check for membership before generating the keys:

```
def items_with_partial_indices(d, i_vals=I, j_vals=J, k_vals=K, g_vals = G, h_vals = H):
    for tup in itertools.product(i_vals, j_vals, k_vals, g_vals, h_vals):
        try:
            yield tup, d[tup]
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for k,v in D.iteritems():
   if i in k and p in k:
       print v
```

Comment: This isn't necessarily correct. What if *i* or *p* (OP's *g*) match *j*, *k* (OP's) or *h*?

Comment: Now it is correct, since i,g are counted on the position for i and g. But i need all elements immediately and not one by one when it appears.

Comment: i added a reference implementation for what i want. But it seems to me a little bit complicated and i wonder if there is a pythonic solution.